# Segmentation Fault when using fopen on argv

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I continue to have a segmentation fault when I try and execute the following code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  if (argc < 4){
     fprintf (stderr,"usage message");
     return (1);
  }

  FILE *src = fopen(argv[1],"r"); //file pointer to inputFile
  FILE *outputFile = fopen(argv[2],"w"); //file pointer to outputFile
  int nth = atoi(argv[3]); //nth term value
  printf("nth term is %d",nth);
  int c;
  int currNum;
  int currCount = 1;

  c = fscanf(src, "%d\n",currNum); //read ints line by line
  while( c == 1 ){
    fscanf(src,"%d\n",currNum);
    ++currCount;
    if (currCount % nth == 0){
      fprintf (outputFile, "%d\n", currNum);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I have to somehow convert argv[1] and argv[2] before I can use them as the file names.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question - but are you actually passing in the correct number of arguments (since there's no check).

Comment: You shouldn't have to convert them. They're legitimate string pointers. Did you check `argc` to determine if `argv[1]` and `argv[2] exist? `argc` needs to be at least `3`.

Comment: if you IDE supports it, put breakpoints and start debugging! You could always put bunch of printfs and see what are the values you are passing in.. and where it actually crashes..

Comment: `argc` needs to be at least 4 (assuming that `stoi()` has undefined behavior if passed a null pointer).

Comment: It would be sensible to check that `argc` is big enough — that you invoked the program with enough arguments.  You probably forgot some, and `fopen()` is failing because you pass it a null pointer.

Comment: You should use `while (fscanf(src, "%d", currNum) == 1)` as the loop condition, removing the `fscanf()` before (probably; unless you really intended to skip the first number altogether) and the `fscanf()` after the `while` line. This will correctly detect EOF, unlike the current code.

Comment: I put in a couple of print statements and have found that the segmentation fault is happening when i hit the 'int nth = atoi(argv[3]);'

Answer (score 1):

Did you provide a command line argument?  You should check that by using an `if` statement before opening the files.  For example, you could add

```
if ( argc < 4 )
{
    printf ( stderr, "usage message\n" );
    return ( 1 );
}
```

Also, change that `stoi` for `argv[3]` to `atoi`.

You don't need to add `\n` for `fscanf`.  Just `"%d"` will do fine.

Comment: I just put in the check to see if there is the correct number of arguments...but now it just seems to sit for a while. I put in a printf in a couple of places (first line of main, after argument check and right before while loop) and I get no output...

Comment: @user3180222: How did you write the check code?  It should print on `stderr` (rather than `stdout` as in the answer at the moment), and then the program should exit (the `return 1;` does that).  There shouldn't be any sitting around.  You should also check that the `fopen()` operations were successful before using the file pointers returned by `fopen()`.  It is good to echo the third argument; it would be better still to echo the first two arguments, especially while you're debugging.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I edited the original code to include the check. What would be the best way to echo the arguments?

Comment: `printf("file1: [%s]\n", argv[1]); printf("file2: [%s]\n", argv[2]);` or equivalent. Note the square brackets around the name to help you identify trailing spaces and newlines, etc.

Comment: After the first `fopen`, check whether the file opened properly.  You could add the statement: `if ( ! src ) { fprintf ( stderr, "Unable to open file %s\n", argv[1] ); return ( 1 ); }`.  Similarly, you can add other checks.  It is always a good idea to check whether the preceding operation succeeded.

Comment: the segmentation fault seems to be occurring at the following line:
int nth = atoi(argv[3]);

Comment: Can you print the value of `argv[3]` using `%s`?

Comment: The `printf` call should be `fprintf`… but SO wants me to change more characters (I didn't dare to do so)…

Answer (score 1):

giving input parameters to `"fscanf"` is wrong. check below one.......

```
c = fscanf(src, "%d\n",currNum);  // wrong
c = fscanf(src, "%d\n",&currNum); 
fscanf(src,"%d\n",&currNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use atoi to convert to int

```
int nth = atoi( argv[3] );
```

You also can `NULL` check file* src and outfile. If you are not giving correct paths then `fopen` may fail.

Comment: +@unxnut's answer for number of argument gaurd